# TexPad Biblatex citing not working

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, texpad

I just started using TexPad but citing is not working. Everything worked fine in Overleaf. But in TexPad citation just doesnt work. I dont get any errors. This is how the start of my document looks like

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[margin = 4cm, top = 2cm, bottom = 2cm]{geometry}  
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Bild} 
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{zitat}

\title{Title}
\author{Jango}
\date {05.02.2019}


\begin{document}
```

This is how my zitat.bib file looks like

```
  @electronic{book,
  address = {Wiesbaden},
  author = {Hippner, Hajo and Hubrich, Beate and Wilde, Klaus D},
  edition = {3., vollständig überarbeitete und erweiterte Auflage},
  hdsurl = {https://hds.hebis.de/hlbfu/Record/HEB232030502},
  isbn = {9783834925503},
  keywords = {},
  title = {Grundlagen des CRM : Strategie, Geschäftsprozesse und IT-Unterstützung},
  uniqueid = {HEB232030502},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-8349-6618-6},
  year = 2011
}
```

When i type \cite{book} TexPad even helps me autocomplete but nothing is cited it just says [book]

Comment: Did you run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 can help you set up your editor for Biber.

Comment: As it turns out our standard editor question does not list instructions for Texpad. I found https://www.texpad.com/support/osx/typesetting/typesetting

Comment: there is so much shit going on with this software when comes to citation...sometimes you just need to restart and everything becomes fine.